# Tags and replacement of terminology

Tags: discussion, tags

As you all know, Salesforce does sometimes change terminology on us. Frequently tags on the site are named after their terminology and thus really need to be updated to the new terminology.

A good example is "community" being replaced by the term "digital experience".

I perhaps naively added a new tag for the latter some months ago and only just got round to noticing I could have perhaps used a synonym.

That said, the tag "community" really should be renamed to "digital-experience" and "community" should become the synonym since it is now an out-of-date term.

Unfortunately, since there are many questions tagged "community" and only a small number tagged "digital-experience", I was not able to make the former a synonym for the latter.

This same problem will occur in each case where terminology changes and tags get left behind.

Anyone know how this could be addressed?

Comment: Mods are able to retag, but I'm not sure that's the proper new terminology. I think what I've heard is "Experience Cloud."

Comment: There are a number of related terms, mentioned [here](https://www.salesforce.com/products/experience-cloud/overview/?bc=OTH) for example. I believe the difference between "Experience Cloud" and "Digital Experience" is that the latter is the metadata and the former is the runtime delivery. In support of the "Digital Experience" term, see this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/set-up-a-community/enable-communities-and-set-permissions) as one example. The Setup UI also calls them Digital Experiences. My tag directly replaced based on the Setup UI change.